# Solving for least surface area of a cylinder with a given volume.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, area

I am doing an online course. The volume is given and I must find the most efficient cylinder, the cylinder with the least surface area. An equation is given and its equivalent. I am not understanding how they went from one formula to another. My algebra mind is failing me.  It is written in my notes as such---  The volume for a cylinder or radius $r$ and height $h$ is a constant and given by $V=\pi r^2h$.  The surface area can be expressed in terms of the radius $r$ as: $$A=2\pi r^2+2\pi rh=2\pi r^2+ \frac{2V}{r}$$   How did they make $2\pi rh$ equivalent to $2V/r$?

Comment: Can you tell me if my logic is right.....

Comment: surface area = 2pir^2 + 2pirh,   I know Volume , and the equation is V= pihr^2.   so in the surface area equation I have 2 unknown terms, r-radius and h-height,    but I know Volume and h height is a term in the equation,  what is the logic jump and rule/principle that allows me to substitute in this equation Volume to remove height?  so after this substitution we only have one unknown term left, radius.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$2\pi rh=2\frac{\pi r^2h}r=2\frac Vr$$

Comment: +1  ,  I didnt see how we subsituted the equation for volume in the equation , I would have never guessed to do that.  Thank you.

Comment: how can we simply substitute in the equation for Volume? are they any rules for this? what is the principle for this type of term substitution in algebra?

Comment: If $A$ is equal to $B$, you can always substitute $A$ by $B$. But you can doesn't mean that you should...