# Relationship between height and radius of cylinder for least amount metal.

Tags: calculus, optimization

I have a quick question to help me with some homework.

If I have a cylinder (with only one end, so open at top), how can I measure the minimum amount of surface area for a given Volume.

So far, I have $ A= 2\pi rh + \pi r^2$
and then $ h = \frac{A-\pi r^2}{2 \pi r}$

Not quite sure where to go next...

Comment: [This question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1018611) has already been answered. There are [thousands](https://www.google.com.hk/search?q=cylinder+with+least+surface+area) of videos that explain the topic, so chances are, there is at least one question on this site.

Comment: What is the formula for the volume of a cylinder?  Is the volume constant or does it vary with the radius in this case?  Lastly, how do you solve a minimization problem, from what you have been taught in your in-class lessons?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint**

Forget about $h= \cdots$ from $A$. 
You have 
$$A= 2\pi rh + \pi r^2$$ which you want to minimize. But you also have $$V=\pi r^2h\implies h=\frac{V}{\pi r^2}\implies A=2 \frac V r+\pi r^2$$ Compute its derivative with respect to $r$, set it  equal to $0$ since you want an extremum. Use the second derivative test to confirm (or not) that this is a minimum.